# php switch statement with multiple expressions

Tags: php, switch-statement

i have 6 html select boxes. Each select box contains three value (recent-media,popular-media,comments-media) and i have variables `$item->content1` to `$item->content6` each variable return to select box. and i create this code below by switch statement because i want use switch statement one time instead of use it 6 times.

the code work but every time return to recent-media and not return to popular and comment media. How i can fix this problem until my code correctly and return for all cases?

```
function YPE_bsn_show_diffcontent(&$item_output, $item) {
        switch (true) {
            case ($item->content1 == 'recent-media' OR $item->content2 == 'recent-media' OR $item->content3 == 'recent-media' OR $item->content4 == 'recent-media' OR $item->content5 == 'recent-media' OR $item->content6 == 'recent-media'):
                YPE_Bsn_Content::YPE_bsrecent_media($item_output, $item);
                break;
            case ($item->content1 == 'popular-media' OR $item->content2 == 'popular-media' OR $item->content3 == 'popular-media' OR $item->content4 == 'popular-media' OR $item->content5 == 'popular-media' OR $item->content6 == 'popular-media'):
                YPE_Bsn_Content::YPE_bspopular_media($item_output, $item);
                break;
            case ($item->content1 == 'comment-media' OR $item->content2 == 'comment-media' OR $item->content3 == 'comment-media' OR $item->content4 == 'comment-media' OR $item->content5 == 'comment-media' OR $item->content6 == 'comment-media'):
                YPE_Bsn_Content::YPE_bscomments_media($item_output, $item);
                break;
            default:
                $item_output .= 'You don\'t selected content for first column';
                break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not switching a variable but a constant then the result is always the same

```
     switch (true) {

         case 
             .....
    }
```

switch the proper related var

```
     switch ($item->content1 ) {
           case 'recent-media': 
                your code fo recent media 
                break;
           ....
           case 'popular-media': 
                your code fo popular media  
                break;
           case 'comment-media': 
                your code fo comment  media 
                break;
    }
```

Essentially you use the swithc in wrong way see php doc for proper use

in  your case you need if (and not switch)

```
  function YPE_bsn_show_diffcontent(&$item_output, $item) {
        if  ($item->content1 == 'recent-media' OR 
              $item->content2 == 'recent-media' OR 
              $item->content3 == 'recent-media' OR 
              $item->content4 == 'recent-media' OR 
              $item->content5 == 'recent-media' OR 
              $item->content6 == 'recent-media')  {
                YPE_Bsn_Content::YPE_bsrecent_media($item_output, $item);
                return;
        }
        if  ($item->content1 == 'popular-media' OR 
              $item->content2 == 'popular-media' OR 
              $item->content3 == 'popular-media' OR 
              $item->content4 == 'popular-media' OR 
              $item->content5 == 'popular-media' OR 
              $item->content6 == 'popular-media') {
                YPE_Bsn_Content::YPE_bspopular_media($item_output, $item);
                return;
        }
        if  ($item->content1 == 'comment-media' OR 
              $item->content2 == 'comment-media' OR 
              $item->content3 == 'comment-media' OR 
              $item->content4 == 'comment-media' OR 
              $item->content5 == 'comment-media' OR 
              $item->content6 == 'comment-media') {
                YPE_Bsn_Content::YPE_bscomment_media($item_output, $item);
                return;
        }

       $item_output .= 'You don\'t selected content for first column';
       return ;
    }
```

Comment: that means i use switch statement 6 times! before i used your way and worked for me without problem. but i search fro best and short way until i collect all `$item->content1-6` in one switch statement because all `$item->content1-6` have the same values. Is i can do this?

Comment: I have update the answer for the (i hope) the best solutions ,, (in this case)

Comment: also same result as in switch statement. I don't know why

Comment: Have you check the real content of $item? try with a var_dump($item) before call the function ..